# How to climb down ladders instead of just falling from them?

Tags: unturned

Every single time I try to climb down a ladder, what happens instead is this:

So, is there a better way of climbing down that does not involves dying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nelson Sexton, the game creator and developer, said to me there is a way, even on O'Leary Prison, to climb down safely.

> ### My original email
>
> Are you aware of the problem that it is not possible to climb down ladders Prince Edward Island's O'Leary
> Prison's guard posts without falling, breaking bones, and bleeding to death?
>
> The "F" interaction to climb down does not shows up there, or shows extremely rarely (never showed up for
> me) on the most recent version. That is a major flaw that penalises the player for a reason beyond its control. This makes O'Leary Prison a really unfunny place to visit.
>
> ### Response
>
> I just double-checked and was able to climb down safely. That being said, ladders in Unturned are certainly frustrating.
>
> For
> cases like that the safest way to climb down is walk backwards off the edge and then press F while your cursor is over the
> ladder. The way the "press F to climb" works it needs to have line-of-sight from the player to the side of the ladder,
> otherwise it would be easy to exploit to go through walls.
>
> Ideally what will happen in the future is a new ladder model with
> new behaviour: standing at the top looking down should give the option to start climbing. The problem is that the existing
> ladder models have been placed stacked up on thousands of community-made maps, whereas the new ladder behaviour like that would need a "top"
> section model and clearly defined "front" side.

[Screenshot of reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6HAK.png)

Answer (score 3):

As of patch 3.22.8.0 (April 22nd 2022), you can mount ladders by looking at them and pressing F. A prompt should appear.

[image: Looking at ladders post 3.22.8.0 gives the option to mount them by pressing F]

The [patch notes](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/304930/view/3212764792084517887) point to the issue of climbing down ladders being finnicky as the direct cause of this change.

> **After the character movement update it became more difficult to climb down ladders**, so at long last you can optionally press the Interact key to mount at the point you are looking! Hopefully this reduces the number of hospital visits caused by jumping to climb down. Walking into a ladder to climb is also still supported.

---

A faster (since looking at ladders to mount to climb down requires a specific angle), but riskier, way to climb down ladders would be to walk backwards, jump, and then immediately hold forwards (or press F) to mount the ladder.

Comment: I never was able to press F while climbing down because I normally fall from it while searching for the right angle. Press F to climb up is easy, though.

Comment: Is there a way to circumvent ladder not showing "F" to climb down on O'Leary prison? This would solve my problem.